# How to filter an array of objects with another array, based on values in the arrays of objects's property?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects named profiles:
[{id: 0, subcategories: ['A', 'B', 'C']}, {id: 1, subcategories: ['A']}]

I have an array named tags: ['B']

I want to filter profiles, only keeping profiles that have a value in tags. In this case, profile with id = 0 would be saved.

This is what I have tried so far and it doesn't seem to be working:

```
      let filtered_profiles = profiles.filter((profile) =>
        tags.includes(profile.subcategories)
     );
```

Comment: `let filtered_profiles = profiles.filter((profile) => profile.subcategories.some(sub => tags.includes(sub)));`

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach. If profiles subcategories includes at least one tag, push it into the result object.

```js
let profiles = [{id: 0, subcategories: ['A', 'B', 'C']}, 
                     {id: 1, subcategories: ['A']}];

let tags = ['B'];
let result = [];

profiles.forEach(function (p){
let copied = false;
  tags.forEach(function (t) {
    if (p.subcategories.includes(t) && !copied) {
      result.push(p);
      copied = true;
    }
  })
});

console.log(result);
```